# Probability of chossing two points from a segment of length L so that one is 2L/3 greater than another.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Two points are selected randomly on a line of length $L$ so as to be on the opposite sides of the midpoint of the line. In other words, two points X and Y are independent random variables such that X is uniformly distributed over $(0,L/2)$ and Y is so over $(L/2,0)$. Find the probability that the distance between these two points is greater than $2L/3$.

Here's what I have done.

[image]

Can I get some help to finish this.

Comment: Not help finishing but a suggestion on how to start. You can assume $L=2$. Then find the area of the part of the unit square that satisfies your condition. (This may in fact be what you've done, with the picture making the calculations clearer,.)

Comment: Ah. Quite good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Let $L=2$ and define $A=1-X$, $B=Y-1$, then $Y-X=A+B$. $A$ and $B$ are then i.i.d. over $(0,1)$ and you are looking for $P(A+B\ge\frac{4}{3})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this make sense to you? I think this aligns with what Ethan has commented.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

A picture, as provided by J. Wang, is very useful for intuition (and has my +1!), but it does need to be made into a rigorous proof. My suggestion is to try conditioning on the first point, $\ell_1$. Once you know this, you can ask "Which options for $\ell_2$ give the required condition?"---this clearly depends on $\ell_1$.

- If $\ell_1 > L/3$, then clearly no $\ell_2$ will suffice.
- If $\ell_1 \in [0,L/3]$, then any $\ell_2 \in [\ell_1+2L/3,L]$ will suffice.

Given $\ell_1$, and that we land in the second scenario, there is a probability $L - (\ell_1 + 2L/3) = L/3 - \ell_1$ that we have the desired property.
Averaging over $\ell_1$, we find that the desired probability is
$$ \textstyle \int_0^{L/3} (L/3 - \ell) f_1(\ell) d\ell
\quad\text{where}\quad
f_1(\ell) = 1/(L/2) = 2/L \text{ is the pdf of $\ell_1$}. $$
Note that this integral is equal to
$$ \textstyle (2/L) \int_0^{L/3} \ell' d \ell' = (2/L) \cdot \tfrac12 (L/3)^2 = L/9. $$